The Git pull encounter issue "RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 7 was not closed cleanly: CANCEL (err 8)"
I'm having trouble running git pull from my repository. The command fails with the following error messages:
remote: Enumerating objects: 42, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (34/34), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (11/11), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 7 was not closed cleanly: CANCEL (err 8)
error: 4136 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: unpack-objects failed

It seems like the operation is failing during the transfer. I've tried running the command multiple times, but I keep getting the same error.

Increased the Git buffer size using the following command, but it didn’t resolve the issue:
git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000


Checked my internet connection, which seems stable and works fine with other services.



For me, only using SSH instead of HTTP solves the problem.
